# Guard not returning authenticated user

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have created a guard

```
@Injectable()
export class EmailConfirmationGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const request: RequestWithUser = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

        console.log(request.user);


        if (!request.user?.hasEmailConfirmed) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Confirm your email first before updating your profile");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And i am using it on of my endpoints

```
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    @UseGuards(EmailConfirmationGuard)
    @Post("/update-profile")
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
    async updateProfile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File, @Body("full-name") fullname: string,@Request() req) {
```

The point is it is faling because getRequest is not returning the authenticated user it is returning undefined

```
const request: RequestWithUser = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
```

How can i return the authenticated user from the response ?

Comment: I assume it's async code running and you need to `await` it with `async/await` ? Are you using a library as well rather than just tagging this with plain `javascript` it might be worth tagging the library

Comment: I am using nest js

Comment: @Thymeleaf you should add the nestjs tag on the question

Comment: what about `@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, EmailConfirmationGuard)`?

Comment: @Miceal Thank you but i got the same

Comment: You only have the `EmailConfirmationGuard` bound via `@UseGuards()` at the route level, and not at the controller or global level, right?

Comment: Yes @Jay McDoniel

Comment: Then using `@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, EmailConfirmationGuard)` like Micael suggested should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use your JwtAuthGuard at your controller level since nest doesn't have an order to run the decorators.

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
export class YourController{

@UseGuards(EmailConfirmationGuard)
@Post()
public async yourFunction() {}
    
}
```